# Can't run another application, when I start debugger

Tags: linux, qt, debugging, ubuntu-14.04, qprocess

I'm programming in Ubuntu 14.04 with Qt 5.3. I want to run an external application `system("flowgeneratormanager &");` from my host app.The external app is in `/usr/bin/` directory.

When I run my host application, <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>, everything is fine.
But when I start my host application in debug mode, <kbd>F5</kbd>, the external application doesn't start, and debugger can't continue after calling `system("flowgeneratormanager &") OR QProcess::startDetached;`

I created a test app, and just started another application in it. after I started debugging, QtCreator showed a dialog that says:
The gdb process has not responded to a command within 40 seconds ....
any idea?
sorry about my bad grammar.its not my mother language.

Comment: You don't show enough code, and you question is not clear enough. Why do you call `system` to run a process in the background? Better use `fork` and `execve` as explained in [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). I don't understand what you mean by "debugger can't continue"? What `gdb` commands did you type? How is your program compiled?

Comment: I have to program in Qt5.3. Actually, I can't call system(). I just wanted to test it.

Comment: So what? You could use `fork` with Qt, and you should use `QProcess` and read its documentation. However, you need to understand the basics (and that means understanding `fork` and `execve`). Did you use `strace` on your program? I don't understand what you mean by "debugger can't continue" (you need to use `gdb` on the command line) - and `QProcess` should work on every Qt implementation (even on Windows)

Comment: These programs should work in windows too. No, I have not used strace yet. QtCreator uses gdb internally. Yes. QProcess should work, but it does not. this is the problem.

Comment: `system("flowgeneratormanager &") OR QProcess::startDetached` is nonsense. Is it your real code?

Comment: I tested function system, and QProcess with many different external applications. Actually, flowgeneratormanager is a 'Test' GUI program, that I used in place of my real external application. The logic is the same

Comment: I created a test app, and just started another application in it. after I started debugging, QtCreator showed a dialog that says: The gdb process has not responded to a command within 40 seconds .... any idea? sorry about my bad grammar.its not my mother language.

Answer (score 2):

In QtCreator, do as following:

> Tools > Options > Debugger > GDB Extended > Uncheck "Debug all child processes"

This should allow Qt not to debug the child process and let it start independently.

Comment: Thanks. This solves my problem! You may accept your own answer.